# QueryDSL throwing could not resolve property exception

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

We are using QueryDSL in our project and adding the predicates JPA is creating below query,

[select transaction
from com.fl.bpm.api.beans.Transaction transaction
where transaction.thread.fulfProject.process.processLabel = ?1 and exists (select 1
from transaction.thread.fulfProject.projSub as transaction_thread_fulfProject_projSub58e1f
where transaction_thread_fulfProject_projSub58e1f.subscription in (select subscription
from com.fl.bpm.api.beans.product.subscription subscription
where lower(subscription.product.flProduct.productDesc) like ?2 escape '!')) and (transaction.thread.fulfProject.isHeld is null or transaction.thread.fulfProject.isHeld = ?3) and transaction.thread.fulfProject.isCancelled = ?3 and transaction.exitDate is null]

And after creating all predicates am executing the query like below,

```
batIter = batRepo.findAll(builder);
```

But the query is throwing below error,

Caused by: 
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: subscription of: com.fl.bpm.api.beans.Thread.

Cause from Stack Trace:

```
    Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: subscription of: com.fl.bpm.api.beans.BpmProjectThread
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1978)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:500)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:652)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:946)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1267)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4686)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:796)
```

Please help me in this :).

Regards,
Sathish

Comment: so it can't find that property of that class. This is the class you haven't posted. Likely people here will be stuck on it for a week if it isn't posted :-P

Comment: LOL Thanks for your comment  .. The classes are too big to post here Neil. Is this correct transaction_thread_fulfProject_projSub58e1f where transaction_thread_fulfProject_projSub58e1f.subscription  i mean aliasname.entity name?

Comment: And yes, Thread table would not have property subscription. and further to clarify, the join here goes like this, transaction -> thread -> project -> projSub -> subscription.